# Java CSSParser assistance

Tags: java, html, css, css-parsing, sac

Except for [this](http://sourceforge.net/p/cssparser/discussion/283564/thread/6e3d60ac), I haven't found any guides on how to use the [CSS parser](http://cssparser.sourceforge.net/), so I'm kind of lost, especially because I'm not very familiar with CSS. I need to obtain images hidden in a css of a webpage, and the getMedia method looks promising.

What should I give the parser as a source? Giving it the html of the page (with the embedded css) doesn't seem to work. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: The page you link to says that it "inputs Cascading Style Sheets Level 2 source text" or in other words, a .CSS file. So try it with a .CSS file first, and if that works, we'll worry about getting the styles from a HTML page...

Comment: It works with a .css file. Can we start worrying about getting a css from a html?